# Could not load type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClientExtensions' from assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

How can get rid of this problem? I have asp.net MVC 4.0 beta installed on my machine, as I have read in some forum that it is creating conflict, and if you uninstall it should work fine. However, my concern is that do I have to reinstall the MVC 4.0 beta to make the web application work built using MVC 4.0 beta. don't know really.

your answer will be appreciated.

> Could not load type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClientExtensions' from
> assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=4.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                var responseStartSchecdule = httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(
                "http://dev02.xav.com/api/Track/StartScheduleRumble",
                CancellationToken.None
            ).IsCompleted;
                
                var responseFinishSchecdule = httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(
                "http://dev02.xav.com/api/Track/FinishRumble",
                CancellationToken.None
            ).IsCompleted;
                
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // add tracing implementation here to trace if there is some error      
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Install RC over Beta - no need to uninstall Beta. See my blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/06/12/asp-net-mvc-4-beta-to-mvc-rc-upgrade-instructions.aspx  When MVC 4 RTMs, install that

Comment: Yap, I have tried myself before you mentioned, and it worked. any ways thank you. how can i mark it as answer?

Answer (score 2):

There have been a couple of breaking changes between the Beta and the RC. Having both installed at the same time is not recommended. So I would recommend you uninstalling the beta, installing the RC and then recompiling your application against the RC. Or if for some reason you want to stick with the Beta you will have to ensure that you haven't downloaded some assembly (or installed via NuGet) that depends on the RC.

Comment: i have only installed the beta version on my machine

Comment: Yes, but you seem to be using some assembly that depends on the RC that's why you are getting the conflict. I recommend you installing the RC.

Comment: I guess you are right. however, what if i want to stick with beta version right now.can beta and RC exist side by side? furthermore, it will not impact on application developed using beta. right?

Comment: In this case you will have to go through all the dependent assemblies that are referenced in your project and ensure that they don't rely on RC code which according to the error message you are getting is the case.

Comment: i have installed the rc using nuget command in particular application. however, still getting the same error. how can refer the assemblies from within the project instead of GAC?

Comment: If your application is compiled against the RC assemblies, then they will be used from the bin folder instead of using the Beta assemblies in the GAC. So there's nothing in particular that you need to do, other than ensuring that your code doesn't depend in a Beta assembly.

Comment: i have added code in original question, which may be of some help to find resolution.

Comment: No, the code is of no help. You have assembly reference conflicts. But I am afraid that you may not be able to have the Beta and RC running side by side.